# Is "Gamble more for less" a common expression?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

Example,

Odds are you're going to die screaming while injecting yourself

Well, I've "gambled more for less"

Answer (score 1):

I have am not sure what “Odds you are going to die screaming while you inject yourself” means without more context.

But

> I’ve gambled more for less”

is perfectly understandable. It means

> I have wagered more money with a lower expected payoff.

The implication then is that the intended meaning is that

> my life is worth less than the potential pleasure of taking this drug.

Please give more context.

Upon reflection, it seels like an old trope, just awkwardly expressed. Poets did a better job, for example Keats:

> I have been half in love with easeful Death

or Swinburne:

> From too much love of living,
> From hope and fear set free,
> We thank with brief thanksgiving
> Whatever gods may be
> That no man lives forever,
> That dead men rise up never,
> That even the weariest river
> Winds somewhere safe to sea.

Comment: I (Dutch native) never heard of them before, and I suspect many ESLs don't. It's *always* better to source quotes, and some users might not even realize you didn't write those yourself.

Comment: Well I am certinly not trying to pass myself off as Keats or Swinburne. And thanks for looking up the quotations. I am getting old and my memory is a bit wonky. I am going to approve your proposed edits as soon as I can figure out how to do so